# In .Net Core for the user to select the download file storage path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

In .Net Core for the user to select the download file storage path
(As long as the path, do not do other things)
I tried Kendo-Ui but unfortunately he only upload function, I do not need the function or I did not find the right way.

Comment: This is totally unclear for me.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Sorry,You mean you can not understand my question?

Comment: I wanna catch and show the file storage path which user choose, no need to do any action(upload, download)

Comment: Yes, it is confusing. You didn't specified how user selects; where the path comes from...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown User can click the button to display the "File Explorer" dialog box, then select the file path.

Functions similar to FolderBrowserDialog.